# date range picker get current dates in the end range

Tags: javascript, forms, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using flask to build some small application. I would like to build a form that collects a start date and an end date. Ideally I would like this form data to my database to run some search on date range. I found some example that is fairly close to what I am trying to do. One thing that I cant figure out is in the example the date range is predefined. I would like for at least the end date to be updated with the current date and not a predefined field.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>


<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<input style="width: 40%" class="form-control" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
{
    locale: {
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
    },
    startDate: '01-01-2013',
    endDate: '12-31-2013'
}, 
function(start, end, label) {
    alert("A new date range was chosen: " + start.format('MM-DD-YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute 'moment()' for the hardcoded end date.

Example:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
{
    locale: {
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    },
    startDate: '2013-01-01',
    endDate: moment()
}, 
function(start, end, label) {
    alert("A new date range was chosen: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});
```

(Also, not sure if this was a copy/paste issue - but you are missing the 'https:' prefix on your script and stylesheet imports.)

Comment: Was gonna add, is moment needed? Date.now()?

Comment: @Akin Yes, or "new Date()". Just used moment because it was there. I wasn't sure if the datepicker was smart enough to handle time values in the config, so originally I was using moment to strip the time.  When I saw it didn't matter, I left just moment().